# Eclipse autocompletion problem

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, shortcut

Just installed Eclipse Helios (Win7 64) and I'm having a strange problem. I type syso-Ctrl-Space which is expected to complete to System.out.println("") but it doesn't work! I searched the web for about an hour now, I set Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist to defaults, nothing. Everything else seems to work. Ideas?

To be clear: the shortcut works, it completes everything except "syso" as seen so far, on syso (also tried sysout) it says "No Default Proposals". I couldn't find this kind of shortcuts in the Content Assist, but I set them to default anyway.

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/heliossr2 is this what you have? The Java version? Not classic eclipse or some other stuff.

Comment: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110218-0911

Comment: Mine also doesn't autocomplete that particular string. Usually it goes like Sys(auto-complete).out.pr(auto-complete)()

Comment: You mean it's a problem with this Eclipse version? It worked in Galileo and previous...

Comment: Have you recently installed any tools that could be catching that keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Autocompletion works. It completes for everything I tried so far, except "syso".

Comment: please see my answer, i don't see why all these invalid comments... this is a good question and has an answer

Answer (score 17):

If you still cant get auto-completion working,try enabling the **Template proposals** under **Content assist** menu.This is the exact location,

```
Windows->Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced
```

And make sure you have only one entry for **syso**(Under **Templates** menu).

Answer (score 9):

I believe the right template is "sysout" and I believe this can be configured somewhere but could not tell you where. Try sysout and then Ctrl+Space
It's a template, you can find all templates under

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates

There you can see that the template name is "sysout" this will then trigger the string substitution for System.out.writeln() but you can change both the template name (if you prefer syso) and/or the actual code produced by invoking the template

Cheers

Comment: Thanks. I must say I couldn't get it to work the way it's set by default, but I created my own template "syso" with type "Java" which worked. Thanx all :)

Comment: Sysout > ctrl + space was giving me print statement until just now. Now, it gives me this choice `private void Sysout() {//TODO Auto-generated method stub}`. Why does this happen ? The template says `System.out.println(${word_selection}${});${cursor}`. What gives ?

Comment: Damn...got the reason. I was doing Sysout, outside of a code block/method.

Answer (score 4):

I am using Eclipse Galileo and had the same problem. Even after trying the above proposed solutions but it didn't work. After making the below change it finally comes out.

1. Go to  Windows->Preferences->Java->Editor->Templates
2. Select sysout template and edit it.
3. Change the context from Java statement to Java.

And it worked for me. I hope this will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 3):

As Peter stated, it is under Window -> Java -> editor -> templates.
Look for the line with the following values.

**sysout** "Java Statements" "Print to standard out" "on"

the preview should be as follows...

```
System.out.println(${word_selection}${});${cursor}
```

Comment: Yep, it's there. I set it default too, and it's on. Still doesn't work (I'm supposed to write sysout and autocomplete? tried that).

Comment: One question, one thought.  1. Are other autocompletes working, like "syserr"?  2. Perhaps for some reason, the IDE, doesn't think you are working with a Java file, Right-click the file, then properties, then look at "Type" to see.

Comment: You have to enable "Template proposals" for java code related auto-completion.Refer my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Your cursor needs to be located in a place where it would be legal to get that line.  If your cursor is within a method definition and you type syso  you will get the replacement.  However if your cursor is in the portion of the text outside of any method definition, say where you declare variables for your class for instance, then syso will not suggest the illegal line system.output.println();.

I had this problem, read all the answers here, became convinced that it MUST be working in my copy, and realized I had been typing syso BELOW the closing } of my last method instead of in the method.

Eclipse on!

Comment: Hi mwengler,
like I said here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358767/eclipse-helios-auto-completion-templates-bug
I type it right. I also said that if I type it manually it compiles and works, only the autocomplete doesn't work. It seems to be a very rare bug since people just don't believe me :) and it happenes in only one class I've seen so far, but I'll say again: I type legal code in a legal place, I'm not new to programming in Java.

Comment: Note that it's not always 'syso', many other auto-comp don't work in certain methods. The only thing special about this class is the code "depth" - It has inner classes, in which I have implemented methods that open threads getting runnables implementing run() etc etc... But I'd like to say that in the first 100 lines everything works fine, it's the lower lines where I had to write everything manually.

Comment: I added the class in my answer. Not the best design but that's what I did then. For instance, where I print "file loaded" or "loading backup" it didn't complete syso, but as you can see it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to set the shortcut of Content Assist with ALT+L, if it works, then you can choose your favorite shortcut again. (The shortcut Ctrl+Space conflicts with the shortcut of switching input method). In eclipse on linux, the shortcut of Word Completion is ALT+/, so if you set this as the shortcut of Content Assist it also conflicts.)

Answer (score 1):

Just go to the below address:

Windows->Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced

and click restore default..........that's all

its work like a charm again.

Answer (score 0):

Also check in this eclipse menu:
Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Appearance -> Type Filters

If you see `java.*` or `javax.*` here then try removing it (or Restore Default will do the job) and see that works, it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution for Eclipse Luna: write syso and press CTRL+Space and click on "enable intelligent code completion" and you are set.
I am sure you can find it somewhere in the options as well but this way it is fast and easy!

Answer (score 0):

DIRTY WORKAROUND:
You can try out the following AutoHotkey-Code if you're still struggling like I am (STILL haven't been able to fix it myself)

```
#persistent
#ifwinactive ahk_class SWT_Window0  ; eclipse java
:*:syso::
sendraw System.out.println()`;
loop, 2
    send {left}
return
#ifwinactive
```

You need to write this in a .ahk file and run it (AutoHotkey needs to be installed). You might wanna put this file into your startup folder. It's a very useful tool, you might wanna expand it one day.

Answer (score 0):

You might have overlapping shortcuts..  Goto 'Overview' than the 'Keys' subsection. Type "ctrl +space" in the 'filter text' section.  You should see the "content assist" and probably another command with the same shortcut.  If another shortcut does exists, change its shortcut to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates >

Scroll down to **sysout** in the Name column
To change the shortcut to syso click on the name and change sysout to syso manually

Scroll down to **sysout** in Context column
To make the shortcut active change the Context for sysout to Java.

Your welcome :)